Distribution of players in Gambler’s Ruin
In a fair game, with 0.5 chance of winning or losing a large number of players begin at 0, (Zero wins, zero losses) each with ten coins. Players leave the game when they have lost everything or have doubled their stake.
After many iterations the distribution of players at each level, from -10 to +10 approaches that of a cosine function.
Is there any proof of this?
I approached this problem by making a truncated normalized Gaussian distribution by subtracting and adding similar but displaced distribution and then summing them using a Maclaurin expansion for the first 10. This gave a result identical to the Maclaurin expansion of a cosine function.
$$F(x) =   ∑_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^n e^{(x+2n)^2/2π}$$ $$=cos(\frac{πx}{2})*0.092136776$$
Is there a better proof?

You can write a linear equation for the time evolution of this distribution vector.  The limiting shape is determined by the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue; the eigenvectors are standing waves, and the largest eigenvalue corresponds to a single half-period of a cosine wave.  This also lets you say how quickly the distribution approaches the limiting form, in terms of the spectral gap between the first- and second-largest eigenvalues.

@mjqxxxx Got about halfway there. With an eigenvalue of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ I see a sine function in the eigenvector, but largest eigenvalue is actually 1. I took Elementary LinAlg a couple of years ago, but the standing waves and spectral gap I'm not familiar with in this context. Can you give me a little more detail or a link? Thanks

Note that it's really the envelope of the distribution that approaches a cosine... it's always the case that you'll have an even (odd) profit after an even (odd) number of rounds.

Let $p(x,t)$ be the probability of having won $x$ coins after $t$ rounds.
We have $$p(x, t+1)=\frac{1}{2}p(x-1, t) + \frac{1}{2}p(x+1, t).$$ We're supposing the player quits when $x=\pm N$ (here $N=10$), so the boundary conditions will be $p(\pm N, t)=0$; we want to understand the time evolution for $x\in(-N, N)$.  In the absence of the boundary conditions, the evolution equation is translation-independent, so plane waves evolve in an especially simple way:
$$
\frac{1}{2}e^{ik(x-1)} + \frac{1}{2}e^{ik(x+1)}=\cos k \cdot e^{ikx},
$$
so if $p(x,0)=e^{ikx}$, then $p(x,t)=(\cos k)^t e^{ikx}$.  Since the equation is linear, the evolution of a linear combination of plane waves is also simple:
$$
p(x, 0) = \sum_k c_k e^{ikx} \implies p(x,t)=\sum_k c_k (\cos k)^t e^{ikx}.
$$
Plane waves don't satisfy the boundary conditions; but if we form linear combinations of $e^{ikx}$ and $e^{-ikx}$ for particular values of $k$, those do.  In particular,
$$
u_m(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{N}\left(m + \frac{1}{2}\right)x\right),\qquad m=0,1,2,\ldots,N-1
$$
and
$$
v_m(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{N}mx\right),\qquad m=1,2,\ldots,N-1
$$
are, respectively, the symmetric and antisymmetric eigenfunctions, and together form a complete basis for any initial probability distribution.  In particular, when the initial state is $p(x,0)=\delta(x)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_m u_m(x)$, the time evolution is
$$
p(x, t)= \frac{1}{N}\sum_m (\lambda_m)^t u_m(x),
$$
where
$$
\lambda_m = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{N}\left(m + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right).
$$
Now, $\lambda_0=\cos(\pi/2N)=-\lambda_{N-1}$, and these two have the largest absolute value, and so decay the slowest with time.  The result is that
$$
p(x, t) \sim \frac{1}{N}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2N}\right)^t\left(u_0(x) + (-1)^t u_{N-1}(x)\right) = \frac{1}{N}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2N}\right)^t (1 + (-1)^{x+t}) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2N}x\right).
$$

Very elegant method. Thanks. After your comment I was struggling with transition matrices for this and not getting anywhere. Wasn't at all familiar with the plane wave solution to this.
